Ubuntu 24.04 Folder Sharing with Windows 10/11
I spent hours trying to enable Ubuntu folder sharing to work with Win 10/11 and am totally stumped. First some background. This pc used to run Win 10 but I recently reverted it to Ubuntu. My first attempt, after hours of trying, did get file sharing between the two environment to work. I do not remember the specifics but in the end, after all the required sw installed and folder sharing setup, all I needed (as far as I remember) was the line force user = myusername. For unrelated reasons I re-installed windows 10 and shortly thereafter re-installed Ubuntu. From this point I got stuck. No matter what I tried I was unable to share a folder with Windows 10/11. I was, however, able to share Windows folder with Ubuntu.I got to the point where I believe that any of the instructions I have been following do not work under v24.04
I have decided to trash the current install and start from square one. Can anyone direct me to clear and concise instructions?
